# Scheme Editor prog

Tags: scheme, racket

i am trying to develop an editor in Scheme (DrRacket) passing lists into the structures. I handled all the functions of an editor like the keystrokes, backspace, left and right etc but i am not getting the idea of how to implement mouse selection which highlights the selected text. Can any one of you help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a question about dealing with GUI in Racket, then you're better off posting on the mailing list.

Comment: If I might be so bold as to suggest looking at the emacs source code, to see how they do it.
Also, what mouse handling is there in DrRacket?

Comment: You could try looking at DrRacaket's source code https://github.com/plt/racket/